# Shell Command in Jupyter lab with ipykernel not work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I installed **Anaconda and Jupyter lab in "base"** environment.
And, I made new environment named "RLRC_Sensor",
then setted **ipykernel in "RLRC_Sensor" for using Jupyter lab in "base"** environment.
[image]

I made new notebook file with "RLRC_Sensor" kernel, (not base)(Jupyter lab is running on "base")
[image]

When I use shell command, it's still working on "base"
but code is running on "RLRC_Sensor" environment.
[image]
(you can see, "!conda env list" is working on "base")

**It makes problem when i use "!pip install something",
it is installed on "base", not environment of kernel.**

When I check on vscode with jupyter extension,
shell command works on "RLRC_Sensor" well.
[image]

I want to fix to run shell command also work with environment **on Jupyter**. What should I do?

I'm appreciated to read this problem.

Comment: Solution: Firstly, you would need to activate this environment. In your Anaconda prompt, by default, it opens`(base)`. You would need to change it to your desired environment. You can use `conda activate RLRC_Sensor` in the prompt and it will switch to that environment. Now you can install all your dependencies and carry on the work.

Comment: Another Solution: If you want to avoid any CLI hassle, simply open your Anaconda Navigator, and then switch to your environment (the option is there on the top of the screen where you will see it is set by default to `(base)`). Click on that dropdown bar and select your environment. A new UI will open with all the apps installed for that environment. Install all needed apps, and then open the Anaconda Prompt from there and install all your dependencies, and then open a Jupyter notebook from there directly to use that environment.

Comment: @GautamChettiar Thank you so much for your detail explanation. Because I have different type of project, for example deepLearning, web server and software lecture. So I want to use seperate kernel for managing version of modules. However I want to make code with one jupyter workspace. So i installed one jupyter on base, and linked ipykernel for all environment. but i found problem in shell command on jupyter ("!" command). Like what you described, python codes are working on specified kernel. But shell command looks like running on host which was running jupyter server on base. Anyway Thanks!

Comment: @Gautan thanks for contributing, make sure to put answers in the answer box below rather than in the comments to make sure that they remain here forever (comments may be deleted at any time)

Comment: Did you try using `%conda` from https://github.com/minrk/condamagic instead of `!conda`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Caridorc, I didn't think the answer was elaborate enough with a full explanation that's why I put it as a comment.

Comment: @krassowski Thanks It' works for me. I also want to know how to fix some jupyter or ipython code about shell command. Like your advice "condamagic", I want to put "sys.prefix" in "!" command.